# Streaming a long video with AWS Presigned URL, problem with expiring links

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, pre-signed-url

Im streaming a long (1:20 hours) video that is hosted in an S3 bucket with cloudfront, by generating a presigned url and inserting it in the source property of an html video tag. I set the expiration time to 5 minutes.

everything works fine. the problem is in some cases the video stops on its own (in various places, sometime at minute 9, sometime 18. nothing specific) with a 403 Forbidden error, obvoiusly because the browser is trying to retrieve more data and the link was already expired.

sometimes its not stopping at all unless the user moves the time bar around after the link expired, getting the same error always.

what is the right way to generate the link in that use case? I want users to be able to move the time bar around in the video even after the expiration time, as long as the connection is alive, and especially I dont want the video to stop on its own after a while because it expired, but addressing the link for the first time should expire after 5 minutes.

Don't seem to find any information on the matter.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, maybe you can check the trafic to verify

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html):

**When does CloudFront check the expiration date and time in a signed URL?**

CloudFront checks the expiration date and time in a signed URL at the time of the HTTP request. If a client begins to download a large file immediately before the expiration time, the download should complete even if the expiration time passes during the download. If the TCP connection drops and the client tries to restart the download after the expiration time passes, the download will fail.

If a client uses Range GETs to get a file in smaller pieces, any GET request that occurs after the expiration time passes will fail. For more information about Range GETs, see How CloudFront processes partial requests for an object (range GETs)., [see How CloudFront processes partial requests for an object (range GETs).](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RangeGETs.html)

Comment: yeah its definitely what happens, a new request is sent to aws after the expiration time when a user moves the time bar. i dont see a way to deal with that in their docs though, becuase it counts as a new tcp connection...